"systemctl daemon-reload" needs to be run after every update command. How do I automate this?
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS which was recently installed. I've noticed that after running sudo apt update I get these warnings:
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of apt-news.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of esm-cache.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.

After running the sudo systemctl daemon-reload command, do I need to run a package source update again? In addition, I wanted to automate the update command to run the "daemon-reload" command if this warning appears. However, setting up a variable in a bash script to record the output of the sudo apt update command does not show the warnings as those are posted directly in the console output. I have tried using systemctl show --property=NeedDaemonReload --value as someone recommended and also using systemctl status | grep -q "changed on disk", but neither command outputs anything. Is there some way to check if the systemctl daemon-reload command needs to be run and then run it so I can type one command to run a script instead of typing both commands for every update?

Same issue here! I have trying to figure out something from here, but I couldn't: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/32959

I've been an Ubuntu user for years, and I started to see these warnings only recently.  I don't understand why would one want to automate silencing a warning.  I interpret this as something that should not happen. This triggered my curiosity and raised additional questions: Is this something safe? Why on earth is this necessary? Who is modifying those files and why? Is my system compromised? ... Only if I get answers to those questions I would be willing to do something to get rid of the warning.

OUTPUT=$(sudo apt update 2>&1)

if echo "$OUTPUT" | grep -q "changed on disk"; then
    echo "Detected service file changes. Running systemctl daemon-reload..."
    sudo systemctl daemon-reload
else
    echo "No service file changes detected."
fi


If you want to examine the error messages for discovering specific situations or errors and act accordingly, you can capture the error messages redirecting stderr (file descriptor 2) to the same file as stdout (file descriptor 1):
sudo "apt update >/tmp/apt-update.log 2>&1"

or using the combined operator to redirect both at once:
sudo "apt update &>/tmp/apt-update.log"

and then analyzing that file.
Also you can filter and check errors directly using grep, with the use of the combined pipe operator:
if sudo "apt update |& grep -iq 'reload units'" ; then
    sudo systemctl daemon-reload
fi

(Using i option to ignore case and q to check quietly so grep do not print extra text if found)

Thanks that's rad, can you fill in the last part? something like "To address your issue, I will now present relevant information." that'd be supes.

Thanks, Ed Swangren. I was not aware of the difference in wording needed. Fixed the answer.
